# How i can get list of ssh_url repo from gitlab.com

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab

How i can get list of ssh url repo from gitlab.
I have group with some id 56627504, and try to get list of all ssh repository which was created under this group i use

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-pnwcu54ZQKz3gtyG-fty" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/56627504/" | jq -r '.projects[*].ssh_url_to_repo'
```

THis part of my json-object

```
  "id": 56627504,
  "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/groups/awg-roi-new",
  "name": "awg-roi-new",
  "path": "awg-roi-new",
  "description": "",
  "visibility": "private",
  "share_with_group_lock": false,
  "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
  "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
  "project_creation_level": "developer",
  "auto_devops_enabled": null,
  "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
  "emails_disabled": null,
  "mentions_disabled": null,
  "lfs_enabled": true,
  "default_branch_protection": 2,
  "avatar_url": null,
  "request_access_enabled": true,
  "full_name": "awg-roi-new",
  "full_path": "awg-roi-new",
  "created_at": "2022-08-12T12:49:50.607Z",
  "parent_id": null,
  "ldap_cn": null,
  "ldap_access": null,
  "shared_with_groups": [],
  "prevent_sharing_groups_outside_hierarchy": false,
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 39020008,
      "description": null,
      "name": "Roi4cio B4r Db",
      "name_with_namespace": "awg-roi-new / Roi4cio B4r Db",
      "path": "roi4cio-b4r-db",
      "path_with_namespace": "awg-roi-new/roi4cio-b4r-db",
      "created_at": "2022-08-31T08:17:59.863Z",
      "default_branch": "master",
      "tag_list": [],
      "topics": [],
      "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-b4r-db.git",
      "http_url_to_repo": "https://gitlab.com/awg-roi-new/roi4cio-b4r-db.git",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/awg-roi-new/roi4cio-b4r-db",
      "readme_url": "https://gitlab.com/awg-roi-new/roi4cio-b4r-db/-/blob/master/readme.md",
      "avatar_url": null,
      "forks_count": 0,
      "star_count": 0,
      "last_activity_at": "2022-11-09T15:20:16.950Z",
      "namespace": {
```

But if i use code like this its work only for one repo

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: Private-token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/56627504/" | jq -r '.projects[0].ssh_url_to_repo'
```